# How can I show data using a modal popup when clicking a table row using bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a table of students and I'd like to show the details (id, name, age) of modal when clicking a table row on popup.

**ListStudents.xhtml**

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th><center>Name</center></th>
   <th><center>Age</center></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <ui:repeat var="stud" value="#{dataModelBeanD.model}">
   <tr>
    <td>#{stud.name}</td>
    <td><center>#{stud.age}</center></td>
    <td>
     <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Consult">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" >
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-modal-window"></span>
      </button>
     </p>
     <div class="modal fade" id="edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
               </button>
               <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Your Detail</h4>
             </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
               <h:outputLabel value="Name : " styleClass="control-label col-sm-2"/>
         <h:outputLabel value="#{stud.name}" styleClass="form-control"/>
         <h:outputLabel value="Age : " styleClass="control-label col-sm-2"/>
         <h:outputLabel value="#{stud.age}" styleClass="form-control"/>
             </div>
             </div>
        </div>
         </div>
       </td>
   </tr>
  </ui:repeat>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

On JS, I made:

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#mytable #checkall").click(function () {
         if ($("#mytable #checkall").is(':checked')) {
             $("#mytable input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                 $(this).prop("checked", true);
             });

         } else {
             $("#mytable input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
                 $(this).prop("checked", false);
             });
         }
     });
     
     $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
 });
```

Knowing that I found many tutorials to solve this issue if we're talking about static table.
However, as you saw I'm working with a dynamic table and the problem is I obtained the same details of the first row after clicking on the 2 rows like described by [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ACBa.png)

Have you please any idea about solving this issue.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: is modal coming for you on click of that button?

Comment: Hello Sir @Aravind, thanks a lot for your reply, I added a screenshot which explains that after clicking on the blue button(consult) of both the first and the second row, the same popup is displayed with the same details (of the first row).

Comment: try replacing <ui:repeat> with <c:forEach> Hope this must work.

Comment: Hello Sir @Aravind thanks for your reply , I tried with <c:forEach var="stud" items="#{dataModelBeanD.list}">, but that gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on this [Example](http://www.bootply.com/TN4AYw6CwH). And so you can do like that:

**Relevant HTML:**

```html
  <ui:repeat var="stud" value="#{dataModelBeanD.model}">
   <tr>
    <td>#{stud.name}</td>
    <td><center>#{stud.age}</center></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
                 <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>
             </td>
             <td>
     <h:form>
      <center>
       <p:commandLink action="#{dataModelBeanD.performRedirectEdit}" >
        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/pictures/edit.png" />  
       </p:commandLink>
      </center>
     </h:form>
    </td>
     <td>
     <h:form>
      <center>
       <p:commandLink action="#{dataModelBeanD.deleteN(stud.id)}">
        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/pictures/delete.png" /> 
       </p:commandLink>
      </center>
     </h:form>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </ui:repeat>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="">×  </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

            </button>
             <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Relevant JS:**

```html
$(".btn[data-target='#myModal']").click(function() {
       var columnHeadings = $("thead th").map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
              }).get();
       columnHeadings.pop();
       var columnValues = $(this).parent().siblings().map(function() {
                 return $(this).text();
       }).get();
  var modalBody = $('<div id="modalContent"></div>');
  var modalForm = $('<form role="form" name="modalForm" action="putYourPHPActionHere.php" method="post"></form>');
  $.each(columnHeadings, function(i, columnHeader) {
       var formGroup = $('<div class="form-group"></div>');
       formGroup.append('<label for="'+columnHeader+'">'+columnHeader+'</label>');
       formGroup.append('<input class="form-control" name="'+columnHeader+i+'" id="'+columnHeader+i+'" value="'+columnValues[i]+'" />'); 
       modalForm.append(formGroup);
  });
  modalBody.append(modalForm);
  $('.modal-body').html(modalBody);
});
$('.modal-footer .btn-primary').click(function() {
   $('form[name="modalForm"]').submit();
});
```

HTH.